# SQLite: "no such table" in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been following a tutorial online to learn SQLite for my project, but my app keeps crashing with the error that the table doed not exist. However when I view the database with SQLite manager it exists.

This is my code

```
public class SQLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mybook";
private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases";
static Context mCtx;

SQLiteDbHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    mCtx = context;
}

public ArrayList<Model> getDetails(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    //crash occurs here
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM booktable",null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Model count = new Model(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
            modelList.add(count);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return modelList;
}

public void CopyDatabaseFromAssests() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = mCtx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFile = getDatabasePath();

    File f = new File(mCtx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
    if (!f.exists())
        f.mkdir();

    OutputStream myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int lenght;
    while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutPut.write(buffer,0,lenght);
    }
    myOutPut.flush();
    myOutPut.close();
    myInput.close();
}

private static String getDatabasePath() {
    return mCtx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
            + DATABASE_NAME;
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() throws SQLiteException{
    File dbFile = mCtx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    if (!dbFile.exists()){
        try {
            CopyDatabaseFromAssests();
            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"copied from assest",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("error occured",e);
        }
    }
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase
    .CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

 }
}
```

This is my first time using an SQLite database.

Comment: Can you show us your `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: Also your `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` statements are completely empty - You're not creating your table structure at all, so that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I've just noticed your `CopyDatabaseFromAssests()`  function - are you trying to clone the contents of an external .db file into your app's internal database? If so then you need to make that point more clear.

Comment: yes i actually have an external database in my asset folder that i want to use for the project. Sorry if i need to add that in the question

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty major point, because that invalidates both of the answers already given. There was the assumption that your app was unable to find the table because no tables were ever created.

Comment: What happens within `openDatabase()`? Do you see the `Toast` or is the exception thrown?

Comment: No `Toast` the app just crashes at this line `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM booktable",null);`

Comment: So `openDatabase()` is not being called at all? Then that would make complete sense as your database asset is not being copied. Try calling `openDatabase()` before `getDetails()`

Comment: It still crash at same point

Comment: Either way your database is not being copied. Do some additional debugging around `openDatabase()` to ensure it is (a) being called, and (b) that your database is being correctly copied. You'll still get the same error over and over if there is no data within your internal database.

Comment: Okay i will try. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

you must be write table creation code in side the onCreate method,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table "+DataBaseConstants.TABLE_NAME_APPCONFIG + "(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, responseData text NOT NULL,createdDate text NOT NULL)");

}
```

and must be write onUpgrade methode, this method is used to compare your previouse and current database version, and update the table according to ,

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + "write your table name here");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a cannot resolve symbol 'db'. i think it can't access from there